# How do you handle parameters & blocks when dynamically defining a method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Below is code for a class that can dynamically add logging to a method. This works in the case where the method takes no parameters and accepts no block.

How can I rewrite the code, so that I can add logging of a method even if it accepts parameters and accepts a block?

```
class X
    def greet
        puts "hi"
    end

    def self.add_logging(method_name)
        alias_method("original_#{method_name}".to_sym, method_name) 

        #How do i rewrie this to account for method_name's arguments and ability to accept a block?
        define_method(method_name) do
            puts "calling #{method_name}"
            send "original_#{method_name}".to_sym
            puts "done #{method_name}"
        end
    end
end

x = X.new
x.greet
X.add_logging(:greet)
x.greet
```

outputs

```
>hi 
>calling greet 
>hi 
>done greet
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class X
  def self.add_logging method
    alias_method "original_#{method}", method
    define_method(method) do |*args, &pr|
      puts "calling #{method}"
      send "original_#{method}", *args, &pr
      puts "done #{method}"
    end
  end
  def greet person
    puts "hi #{person}"
  end
end

x = X.new
x.greet("Joe")
X.add_logging(:greet)
x.greet("Jane")
```

will give:

```
hi Joe
calling greet
hi Jane
done greet
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have just tried it. I wasn't aware you could use the *args and &block syntax in block parameters.

Comment: You also don't need to do `to_sym`. That is an extra operation, and will slow down the process.

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know the `define_method`-methods block accepts parameters, which represent the method parameters so i'd suggest the following:

```
define_method(method_name) do |*arguments|
        puts "calling #{method_name}"
        send "original_#{method_name}".to_sym, *arguments
        puts "done #{method_name}"
end
```

`*arguments` in the do-part in the block wraps all arguments/parameters which are sent when calling the method `method_name` into an array, and `*arguments` in the send-method call expands them again for use in the original method.

Comment: Right, but I don't know how many parameters the original method accept when I call add_logging, so I can't hard code a specific number of parameters as you've done. Neither will I know if it accepts a block or not, and would like to account for that possibility.

Comment: this works for every arity, since *arguments rolls in all arguments at once.